# Ubuntu MATE: Where is Vino in dconf?

Tags: dconf, mate, vino

I'm running Ubuntu MATE 1.8 (3.16.0-30-generic) and have got remote desktop running but wanted to modify some settings in dconf (Still learning how to use dconf but was able to successfully make changes to my Debian Laptop), but unlike my laptop I can't see the vino entry and don't know where it is.

Have I missed a step? Is it only available through gsettings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vino settings can be found under `/org/gnome/desktop/remote-access/`. You can easily modify them using `dconf-editor`:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

[image]

Comment: @Lennox84: To find the dconf path of vino settings what I did was typing `dconf watch /` in a terminal and changed some settings from the remote application. You should see the corresponding dconf values logged by the above command. HTH