# Remote Desktop Settings aren't allowing setup in Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS?

Tags: remote-desktop, sharing

I am trying to set up remote desktop but on the computer that I'm trying to setup access for, it will not even load the sharing settings. All other settings load fine. I have attached an image of the issue. Essentially, regardless of if I've switched it "on" or "off", this screen does not change,the sharing settings do not appear, so I cannot begin setting anything up. I have set this up on other Ubuntu machines in the past without issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: It is indeed a full install. I've just named it "ubuntu" for the screenshot - my apologies for the confusion. Perhaps something went wrong during the installation though? I just added Ubuntu to this computer yesterday.

Comment: It is possible that the installation didn't go well. I have not done a full install of 14.04.1 yet. I have installed the initial ISO and updated it fully to 14.04.1 and I have upgraded 16.04 to 14.04.1. So, I can't be sure what is causing your problem. Hopefully someone else will have an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps someone like me: Remote Desktop is grayed out in Ubuntu Settings *until* you flick the toggle in the upper right corner, near the Close Window X.

(I can't be the only one who did not expect an unlabeled toggle up there.)

Answer (score 0):

On one of my machines, I had to install vino and dconf-editor:

```
sudo apt install vino dconf-editor
```

then edit the values under `/org/gnome/desktop/remote-access/` (see [Ubuntu MATE: Where is Vino in dconf?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/589062/ubuntu-mate-where-is-vino-in-dconf)).

on another, I had an entry from old times in `/etc/network/interfaces` which I had to remove so that only the following remains:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

then follow [the description on Linux Config](https://forum.linuxconfig.org/t/wired-unmanaged-ubuntu-desktop-issue/1574) - however, I made one change, namely I made NetworkManager manage all connections. So I created a file `/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml` that looks like:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Then reboot and everything worked. Totally crazy, I would really like to know what went wrong at Canonical when they switched from 16.04 to 18.04